# How to change the window title in a Mac Catalyst window scene?

Tags: ios, mac-catalyst, uiwindowscene

I'm opening multiple scenes in the Mac Catalyst version of my iPad app. The problem is that all of the windows simply show my app name in each window title. This makes it confusing looking at the list of windows in the Window menu. Plus I want to specific information to appear in the window title beside the app name.

UIWindowScene has a promising Mac Catalyst-only property named `titleBar` of type `UITitleBar`. Sounds promising but it has nothing related to setting any kind of title. Strange.

There's nothing I can find in the `UIWindowScene` or `UIWindow` classes or anything related to scenes.

I have also tried setting the `title` of the window's `rootViewController`. That had no effect. I also tried various values for the `representedURL` property of `UITitlebar` but that is used for things other than changing the title.

Is there any way to set a window's title in a Mac Catalyst app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how I missed it but it turns out this is trivial.

The `UIScene` class has a `title` property which is exactly what is needed. The value of this property is what is shown in the iPad app switcher as well as in the title bar of the iPad app running on a Mac.

Setting it to nil defaults to the app name. Setting it to the empty string shows no title. And of course setting it to any other value shows that title.

Comment: This works fine in SceneDelegate, but what if I want to change the title in response to user input (suppose I have a project name I want to display and the user wants to rename the project). Updating this from a VC doesn't seem to work. Or do I need to set something like setNeedsDisplay?

Comment: So here's what worked for me. In the view controller, I post a notification that includes userInfo with the new title. Then in the scene delegate, I listen for that same notification. On receipt of the notification, I update the title. Works like a charm.